# problem with Cyrillic chars in tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, encoding, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3, and printing Cyrillic chars is fine.
But when the same string is inserted into the Tkinter listbox, the string remains
unchanged.
The string is:

```
st = '\u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f \u0414\u0440\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0435\u0438\u0306 \u0413\u0440\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0438 \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u044f \u041a\u0430\u0440\u043f\u044e\u043a\u0430.mp4'

print(st)

История Древней Греции Сергея Карпюка.mp4
```

I have tried this build system:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf8"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By running below code, I am able to insert the string into both a label and a listbox, without any issues.

```py
import tkinter as tk

st = '\u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f \u0414\u0440\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0435\u0438\u0306 \u0413\u0440\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0438 \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u044f \u041a\u0430\u0440\u043f\u044e\u043a\u0430.mp4'

print(st)

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text=st)
label.pack()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.insert(0, st)
listbox.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: yes that works for me too. The problem maybe that I use the log file, from which the strings are read. I have tried to use encoding as: with open(LOG, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f: But that truncates the data, I don't get all the strings.

Comment: try `open(LOG, 'rb')` and then decoding the output

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is to use file reading in usual mode and not specifying the encoding in the open(file) command.
Because the log contains filenames in several languages I have had to use 2 try except blocs.

```py
with open(LOG, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for part in line:
            try:
                # this fixes Cyrillic file names
                part = part.encode('utf8').decode("unicode_escape")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            try:
                # this fixes French, German file names
                part = part.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    
            listboxMain.insert(tk.END,part)
```

Comment: The `pass` statements were redundant so I removed them.

Comment: @tripleee, yes you are correct.  I will keep either pass or print statements once the code will be fully functional.